# Namespace not found on extending class

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a problem with namespaces. Follow the code:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class NavBar extends fwportal\controllers\template\NavBar {

    function __construct()
    {
        var_dump('navBarPortal');
        parent::__construct();


    }
}
```

And the main class:

```
<?php

namespace fwportal\controllers\template;
use fwportal\controllers\NavbarPermissoes;

if (!defined('BASEPATH')) {
    exit('No direct script access allowed');
}

Abstract class NavBar extends \CI_Controller
{}
```

This return the error below:

```
Fatal error: Class 'fwportal\controllers\template\NavBar' not found in /var/www/portalsibe/sistema/controllers/template/NavBar.php on line 6
```

Anyone can help me with this?
I don't know why this error occur, because I used in other files with the same mode and works ok.

Comment: Don't know much about CI, but are you using [autoloading](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/autoloader.html)? And where is that source file for `NavBar` located?

Comment: NavBar extends:  /var/www/portalsibe/sistema/controllers/template/NavBar.php

NavBar: var/www/fwportal/sistema/controllers/template/NavBar.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Codeigniter 3 then most probably you can not extend "\CI_Controller" while you are defining namespace on a class.

May be this is the reason of getting error.